# Combining multiple observables and return the observable that does not throw error

Tags: android, merge, kotlin, rx-java, observable

I've two observables, one is to fetch data from remote and another one is used to fetch data from local (local db). What I want is get data from local if remote failed to fetch data. I tried to use Observable.mergeDelayError, but I still get error although one of the observable is success.

Currently this is what I do:

```
    fun getCatalogueDetails(id: String): Observable<CatalogueDetails> {
        if (application.isConnectedToInternet()) {
            return getCatalogueDetailsFromRemote(id)
        }

        return getCatalogueDetailsFromLocal(id)
    }

    private fun getCatalogueDetailsFromRemote(id: String): Observable<CatalogueDetails> {
        return Observable.create { emitter ->
            ApiHelper.getCatalogueDetails(CatalogueDetailsRequestModel(id))
                    .subscribeOn(schedulersFacade.io())
                    .observeOn(schedulersFacade.ui())
                    .subscribe(object : SingleObserverRetrofit<RetrieveCatalogueDetailsResponseModel>() {
                        override fun onResponseSuccess(responseData: RetrieveCatalogueDetailsResponseModel) {
                            responseData.model?.let {
                                val catalogueDetails = CatalogueDetails.fromResponseModel(responseData.model)

                                if (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                                    emitter.onNext(catalogueDetails)
                                    emitter.onComplete()
                                }
                            } ?: kotlin.run {
                                if (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                                    emitter.onError(ErrorUtil.NULL_RESPONSE_DATA_ERROR_EXCEPTION)
                                    emitter.onComplete()
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onFailure(throwable: Throwable) {
                            super.onFailure(throwable)

                            if (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                                emitter.onError(throwable)
                                emitter.onComplete()
                            }
                        }
                    })
        }
    }

    private fun getCatalogueDetailsFromLocal(id: String): Observable<CatalogueDetails> {
        return Observable.create { emitter ->
            schedulersFacade.diskIO().execute {
                appDatabase.runInTransaction {
                    val catalogueDetails = appDatabase.rewardDetailsDao().findCatalogueDetails(id)

                    if (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                        catalogueDetails?.let {
                            emitter.onNext(catalogueDetails)

                        } ?: kotlin.run {
                            emitter.onError(ErrorUtil.LOCAL_DATA_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_EXCEPTION)
                        }

                        emitter.onComplete()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onErrorReturn`. So if the remote call fails, call local.

```
private fun getCatalogueDetailsFromRemote(id: String): Observable<CatalogueDetails> {
    return Observable.create { emitter ->
        ApiHelper.getCatalogueDetails(CatalogueDetailsRequestModel(id))
                .onErrorReturn(e -> {
                    return getCatalogueDetailsFromLocal();
                })
                .subscribeOn(schedulersFacade.io())
                .observeOn(schedulersFacade.ui())
                .subscribe(// Do your stuff)
    }
}
```

Comment: By using this, can I still output the error inside the subscribe?

Comment: Yes, in subscribe, the second argument is the errorHandler.